# How to pass different CorDapp config to different nodes when using MockNetwork

Tags: corda

I am writing a test for flows using MockNetwork. There is a counter-flow on one of the mock nodes that is using CorDapp's `CordappContext.config` to determine the course of action. I am looking for a way to pass config parameters into the CorDapps on individual mock nodes. It does not look like there is a way of doing so through `MockNodeConfigOverrides`, and `TestCordapp.withConfig(...)` only seems to apply to the network level. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have different config map to CorDapps installed on different mock nodes. This has to be done through `TestCordapp.withConfig(...)` passed into `MockNodeParameters.additionalCordapps` when creating each individual node, as opposed to `MockNetworkParameters.cordappsForAllNodes`. Effectively the same TestCordapp needs to be applied to each mock node but the config map will be different.